# QGIS isn't bringing all the features from an WFS URL

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs

I have a geoserver installed and some layers published in it. There is a specific layer that has 70 features. The problem comes out when I try to load this layer in QGIS 2.14, only 19 features are shown.

If I download the shapefile of this layer, there are all the 70 features and even when I try to load the shapefile in QGIS, all the 70 features are shown.

The problem only occurs when I try to load the WFS URL (instead of 70 features, only 19 are shown).

If I try to load the WMS URL, everything is shown correctly.

May someone give a clue?

I'm using geoserver 2.4.4 and QGIS 2.14.

I've already tried using WFS URL with maxFeatures setting it to 100, and no success.

Comment: can you share either the url or the shapefile?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot. I know that won't help me. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This morning, my colleagues and I found the problem that was occurring. There was a record in database with some malformed character in a column and QGIS was truncating from that feature and showing only the features before that one. After correcting the malformed character, everything started to work perfectly. :)

I'll leave this answer here, so someone may try this solution instead of going nuts. Hehehe.